# jQuery .<Something that can automatically run a callback function>(). What would it be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need something like .load() but that can only work for images and iframes. I would want to do this in order to automatically attach a selector element in "this" variable.

```js
$('document').ready(function({
  $('a').<Something to automatically run the stuff below when page is loaded>(function(){
    // Placeholder is to store the href somewhere so the link does not go to a webpage atm.
    $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).attr('href','javascript:');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="www.example.com">My Link</a>
```

Comment: Sounds like something is dynamically adding content and you want to detect that. There is nothing to detect when an element is added. You can use a mutation observer to detect DOM changes or you can trigger an event when you update the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to achieve this simple thing ? :

```
$('document').ready(function({
  $('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).attr('href','javascript:');
  });
});
```

**$('element').each** allows to loop over all elements, and you can use **$(this)** inside closure to modify the element itself.

Comment: It did work lol. DId not know about .each(). I did that in order so that on a mobile device, when tapping a dropdown, if you only want to expand it, instead of directing you to the main link. Did not finish the code yet.

Comment: @RobertMoore I know because I had to wait for a bit of time before accepting it though.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery supports chaining so the simplest and most likely the most performant answer is:

```
$('document').ready(function({
  $('a').each(function() {
    var a$ = $(this);
    a$.attr('placeholder',$a.attr('href'))
      .attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
  });
});
```

Everytime you call `$(this)` it has to create a new jQuery wrapper around `this` which you might as well cache via a variable.